# SQL Server (2005) Query Help

Tags: sql-server

My query is based on the following example

I have table say 'Table1'. Table1 has one row and one column. The name of the column is 'Column1'. 'Column1' is a text column (NVARCHAR). I have a comma separated keywords like 'key1,key2..keyn'. I want to search these keywords individually in the column1.

So in the where clause the query should be something like

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%key1%'
AND Column1 LIKE '%key2%'
AND Column1 LIKE '%keyn%'
```

I just want to know how to write a query in a simplified manner. Table is quite small and performance is not a main concern.

Just declare the keywords in a variable for the test case

```
DECLARE @Keywords NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Keywords = 'Key1,Key2,Key3'
```

A simple example will be helpful to me.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you should also start accepting answers.  You haven't accepted any and it discourages people from assisting.

Comment: Sorry, but how to accept it? Normally I accept via comments if I find satisfactory answer. Is there any way to mark it?

Comment: Click the check box below the vote count.  This gives the answerer 15 extra rep and marks it as the "correct" answer for others who are looking at the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier if you get these into table format. (`Split` Table Valued functions exist to do this to your delimited string - e.g. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/13/10021854/fnsplit.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Keywords TABLE
(
COL NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Keywords SELECT 'Key1' UNION ALL SELECT 'Key2' UNION ALL SELECT 'Key3'

SELECT ... 
FROM Table1  c 
JOIN @Keywords k ON c.Column1  LIKE '%' + k.COL + '%'
GROUP BY  ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) FROM @Keywords)
```